# Configure Chrome to Automatically Load Mobile Versions of Web pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I run Google Chrome on my full size laptop (Win 7), my cell phone (Android), and a rather small Dell netbook (Win XP).  Certain sites will always open the full webpage on the laptop and a special mobile version on the cell phone.

Because the netbook screen is about the same shape as a large tablet, I would like to configure Chrome on the netbook to automatically call for the mobile version.

Can I get this result with some kind of script??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to render a tablet device or other size related in every page the best its to use the Chrome Console, follow this steps:

1. Press F12, the Chrome console will be opened
2. Press Ctrl + Shift + M and you will see a grid and the page renderer as the default size setted in the top left of the page, there you can change the size or emulate devices

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `navigator.userAgent` property, or just use `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` to navigate to the mobile version given a certain size or PPI density.